# retain white spaces in fields when using awk

Tags: awk

I am using nawk on a pipe delimited file to print fields as index and key where some of the fields contain white space, when there is no white space space everything works normal, but in case of white spaces somehow awk treats it as field separator and prints this o/p to new line. se my input below :

Input

```
a|b|c d e|1|2|3
a|b c|d|1|2|2 3
Output
Index=a|b|c
Key=1|2|3
Index=d
Key=
Index=e
Key=
Index=a|b
Key=1|2|2
Index=c|d
Key=3
```

Expected Output

```
Index=a|b|c d e
Key=1|2|3
Index=a|b c|d
Key=1|2|2 3
```

In short for two record 2 Index and 2 keys and keep the basic white spaces as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Without you posting your code it is hard to tell what you are messing up. The following code produces your expected output

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS="|"; }

{
    print "index=" $1, $2, $3;
    print "key  =" $4, $5, $6;
}
```

when fed with your sample input

```
a|b|c d e|1|2|3
a|b c|d|1|2|2 3
```

the output is

```
index=a|b|c d e
key  =1|2|3
index=a|b c|d
key  =1|2|2 3
```

which is what you seem to require. It works because I change the input field separator (FS in gawk) and the output field separator (OFS) to be the pipe symbol, and then just print the first three fields as index and the last three as key.